# how can I edit my code that has shown results separately base on inputs and avoid duplicating

Tags: python, function, output, addition

```
def aplusb(a, b):
    return a+b
    # write your code here

q=0
max=int(raw_input())
while q<max :
    a,b = map(int, raw_input().split())
    q=q+1
# q=aplusb(a,b)*q

for q in range(max):
    q = aplusb(a, b)
    print q


if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = int(raw_input())
    for i in range(q):
        inps = [int(_) for _ in raw_input().split()]
        print aplusb(inps[0], inps[1])
```

when I input two different series of number like `(2,1)` and `(3,6)` I expect the results like this `(3) \N (9)` but they have shown `(9) /n (9)` right now! how can I fix it?

Comment: Could you clarify what your code is supposed to do?

Comment: take a number as counts of your series (for example if u input 3 it means you want put 3 series of number as each one them contents two numbers with space between them) and then add (3 series) them and show you the results (three results)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your code is changing the value of `a` and `b` before it prints out any results of computations on them.

I take it that you do not want the input interleaved with the output. So you have to store either the inputs, or the results, temporarily in a list. This approach stores the inputs because that is closer to your original code.

```
def aplusb(a, b):
    return a+b

inps = []
max=int(raw_input())

for q in range(max):
    inps.append(map(int, raw_input().split()))

# At this point, using your sample data, inps looks like [[2,1], [3,6]]

for a, b in inps:
    q = aplusb(a, b)
    print q
```

As a side note, if you are just beginning Python, you *really should not* be be teaching yourself Python 2. Please consider installing and using Python 3 instead.

Comment: thank you so much, it works ! absolutely python 3 is better

Answer (score 0):

The code before `if __name__`... reads all of the input in the first `while` loop, but then only uses the last `a` & `b` for each iteration of the second `while` loop.

You could print the results for each pair as you read them, or you have to save all of the input so the second loop can go back over it.

Comment: because i used input so i do not how many series of numbers can input so i do not how many print function can be needed